# I want to program STM32 using keil uVision on a macbook with an m2 processor. How to do it and is it possible at all?

Tags: stm32, apple-m1, keil, stm32f4discovery, stm32f4

I have keil uVision on Windows using Parallels. I have STM32(a lot of different) and ST-LINK. So, I want to firmware my program from a macbook with m2 processor. Can I do it?

I tried to find the drivers in the internet, but nothing works. If you can give me instructions on what to do, I will be very grateful to you.

Comment: You cant directly as this prduct does not support mac

Answer (score 0):

Keil as you know is not supported on Unix platforms and as powerful as the MacBook is you cannot use it. However, you can use UTM software, and install Windows 11 for ARM from here:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsinsiderpreviewARM64
You can then install Keil on the windows.
As a fellow MacBook user, I feel left out with Keil not being in support but we do have 2009 options such as Eclipse. Pair eclipse with brew and the terminal and you almost have a Keil experience.

Try out this video of the UTM, Windows 11 procedure:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KGZMV8IuUtA

Answer (score 0):

so for anyone still searching for a solution:

there a macbook arm ( m1, m2 ) alternative from stm:

https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32-ides.html

and also

stm32 cubex

they both work great, at least for my Uni use-case.

just register on their site, you need it to login from the IDE and download the packages from their site^^

hope this helped the community and someone out there.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).